# Converting e+“COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT” to é in Java

Tags: java, unicode

There are 2 ways of presenting é in unicode:

- 2 unicode points: e + ́ (=normal e + "combine with acute
  accent")
- 1 unicode point: é (=e with acute accent)

How can I make sure that a Java string that contains both types is converted to a String that only contains the single unicode point version?

Comment: Google "Java Unicode Normalisation"

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`java.text.Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Normalizer.html) as described in the [*Normalizing Text* tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html). In your case, you'd probably be looking for Normalization Form C (though depending on your precise situation, you may want Normalization Form KC instead, but NFC is usually what you want; see the tutorial for details).

```
normalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(originalString, Normalizer.Form.NFC);
```